# Use enum in LinQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

need help

I have this enum which sets the PayClassNo to Direct and Indirect. I want to use this enum in my LinQ query.

Here's my scratch LinQ query:

```
var jDef = from jd in context.GetTable<RJVDefinition>()
                       select new PayrollJVDefinition
                       {
                           JVdefNo = jd.JVDefNo,
                           AccntCode = jd.AccntCode,
                           AccntDesc = jd.AccntDesc,
                           PayClass = enum.GetValue(jd.PayClassNo),
                           IsFixed = jd.IsFixed,
                           IsEmployee = jd.IsFixed,
                           IsAR = jd.IsAR,
                           CreatedByNo = jd.CreatedByNo,
                           CreatedDate = jd.CreatedDate,
                           ModifiedByNo = jd.ModifiedByNo,
                           ModifiedDate = jd.ModifiedDate
                       };
```

Need help because I'm not sure if this will work.

Comment: What is your question?  Have you actually tried anything at all?  Are we debugging a hypothetical issue?

Comment: How can I use enum in my LinQ query? I know that my "scratch query" won't work here. I'm looking for ways where I can retrieve the enum value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to parse the `Enum` just use something like

```
Enum.Parse(jb.PayClassNo, YourEnumType)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly do the translation in code, similar to your example (using `Enum.Parse`), but you don't need to.  You can use the designer to set the object property type to an enumerated value.  See [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/robp/archive/2008/05/19/using-c-enumerations-as-linq-to-sql-entity-properties.aspx) for details.